# Codeigniter routing return "file not found" after moving to live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, host

In my root directory I have .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

to remove index.php from url.

In my routes.php file I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'absolventi';
$route['absolventi'] = 'absolventi';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Default controller works, but adding /absolventi to domain does not. Every file that is requested returns file not found. Also ajax calls return that.

I tried changing to `$route['absolventi'] = 'index.php/absolventi';` to see if .htaccess overrides index.php but still the same error. Really do not know what else to do. Any help, suggestions would be appreciated. If need more info, ask.

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 1):

if this is your controller name `absolventi` then follow this

File name should be **Absolventi.php**
and inside the file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Absolventi extends CI_Controller {


    public function  __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
```

> Do this for all files in your project. **We call this as naming Conversions**

Read [PHP Style Guidee#file-naming](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html?highlight=file%20name#file-naming)

Comment: I have everything ok with naming Conversions! If there are problems with that, CI returns 404 page. Controler "absolventi" works perfectly when called as base_controller.

Comment: sorry, not as base_controller but as default_controller. The idea is that controller works, there is a problem with routing.

Comment: What exactly should I check? I found similar comment in another question but do not understand what exactly should I check for and how?

Comment: move the files and folders again. (Controller/View and model) and grant 655 permissions to those folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136220/discussion-between-krlis-janisels-and-abdulla-nilam).